# UIPickerView with detailed text

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

fellows!

I am looking for how to create a picker view with label and detailed label like the link below, but I couldn't.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/convert-the-unit-calculator/id325758140?mt=8.
(Sorry, I am not able to post images).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`-[UIPickerViewDelegate pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView%3aviewForRow%3aforComponent%3areusingView%3a).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible to have a detail label in native PickerView. You can create your own custom pickerview from a UITableView, customizing your cells.

Take a look at AFPickerView code [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/afpickerview).